# LC series circuit resonance beyond voltage limits of programmable capacitor - solvable with gain stage?

Tags: passive-networks, resonance

I am replicating a design where a mechanical tuning capacitor is in series with an inductor antenna, in order to achieve resonance at certain (hundreds of kiloHertz) frequencies. I am looking into options for programmable capacitors and have found the IXYS NCD2400 series - unfortunately though, its voltage limits are significantly smaller than what I'm measuring on my fixed-capacitance prototype.

Is there perhaps a way to insert some type of gain stage in between the capacitor and inductor, so that the resonance characteristics are maintained, and the voltage that the capacitor sees is lowered?

Comment: What value of fixed inductance, what range of capacitance do you need? What minimum resolution change do you need in the capacitor? What p-p voltage could be seen across the capacitor? What range limit of frequencies?

Comment: Current fixed inductance is 254 pF; desired range is from 113 pF to 325 pF (which I know is slightly larger than the 192 pF range of the NCD2400). Minimum resolution change would be about 4 pF. Vpp across the capacitor I believe is around 35 Volts. Frequencies between about 300 and 600 kHz, with optional outliers at around 200 kHz and 1 MHz, which I was thinking of reaching with switching in separate capacitors

Comment: *inductance is 254 pF* - inductance is measured in henries or mH or uH or nH.

Comment: My bad - about 0.7 mH

Comment: @Andyaka any ideas/pointers based on this info, please? would a transformer be something worth trying perhaps...

Comment: A transformer could step down the voltage onto the capacitance chip but then the effect of capacitance would be divided by the turns ratio squared meaning that with (say) a 10:1 step down, 100 pF would receive only one tenth of the voltage but, at the primary terminals of the transformer would have the effect of only 1 pF.